# Water solidifies near the bottom of a hypothetically deep oceanic trench

Tags: pressure, water, earth, phase-transition, ice

How deep (kilometers) would an oceanic trench on planet Earth have to be in order for the water to become a solid because of the pressure from the water column? For simplicity, maybe assume chemically pure water, and a constant temperature of 300 kelvin of the entire body of water. An answer with realistic amounts of salt and with temperatures at each depth corresponding to the ambient lithospheric temperature would be welcome too, of course.

It can be assumed that the trench is so narrow that the change in global sea level is negligible.

I considered asking the same question for an air-filled well, in contact with the atmosphere, but I realized that the critical temperature for air is only 133 kelvin, so there would be no depth at which a phase transition would occur.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/hydrostatic-pressure-doesnt-density-vary-with-depth

Comment: For water at zero Celsius, you need a pressure of 632 MPa (see wikipedia article on phase diagrams - it has the P-T diagram for water). 1 atmosphere is 101 kPa, so this is roughly 6000 atm. 300K will take a higher pressure, but the ocean is not that warm.

Comment: After I submitted the question, a very related thread shows up in the column at the right: [Does water turn solid under deep ocean because of high pressure?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108816/)