# How deep must Earth's ocean be to form Ice VII on bottom?

Tags: pressure, water, estimation, planets, ice

Is there way to tell how deep must Earth's ocean be to form Ice VII on bottom? Or is it impossible because of our planet is too small?

As I know, in 11.5km Mariana Trench there is 108 MPa and to form Ice VII u need 3GPa. But 11.5km is nothing compared to size of Earth right?

Comment: can we extend this question to include ice VI?

Comment: oh, and Ice III and V as well ... it is cold at the bottom on the ocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ice VII occurs above 3 GPa. Pressure at depth $z$ is $p =\rho g z$, so the critical depth for $\rho=1050$ kg/m$^3$ is $z=290,951.4$ m. So we need a 291 km deep ocean to get high pressure ice. Not very likely on Earth.

Comment: On this image is rough representation of this 290,9km deep sea: https://imgur.com/a/SopRncv . I think its 100% possible :D :D :D Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Baterka - I would like to draw your attention to the maximum height of mountains when you consider the maximum depth of a trench in the earth filled with water ... the density of water is only about 1/3 that of granite